# How to add user-defined functions in code.gs in the Google Script Manager

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to add my own functions to a Google Apps script attached to a spreadsheet but I keep getting the error "Missing formal parameter".  My fundamental problem is that I don't understand how the different functions and .gs files in the Script Manager interact...

In the Script Manager, I've already modified Code.gs and it does what I intended.  I'm now trying to add a second function to Code.gs:

```
function sliceCol(2darray, col){
   var column = [];
   for(var i=0; i<2darray.length; i++){
     column.push(2darray[i][col]);
   }

   return column;
}
```

"2darray" and "col" are not defined elsewhere and are placeholders for the 2darray and integer that I want to pass to this function.

Can someone please help me understand how to do this?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple errors.
1) you cant pass an array object to a custom function, just cell values.
If you must pass an array build it manually as json.
2) you are returning a row not a column. As is it will expand horizontally. You need to return like an array of rows as in [[x],[y]].

Regarding (1) it will be harder if your range has variable size because you cant pass a range name you have to pass its values.

Comment: Re JSON: Could you give an example of how that would work with something like [[a,b,c],[1,2,3],[A,B,C]] please?  Re row not col: I'm counting through the rows of 2darray with a fixed column index - surely, that returns a column?

Comment: As for the columns vs. row, a column is really an array of rows where each row has a single cell. For example [[0],[1],[2]] would represent a column, but [0,1,2] is a row, and you are building your "column" like the former example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I was stuck thinking more about matrices than lists.  I've got follow-up questions, but I'll look them up first and post them separately, if appropriate.